# Add javascript object to spring form by clicking a list element

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I got a list of products created from an ajax call. This list shows the names and product numbers of the products. 
Now I want to add products to a form by clicking on a list element in the list of products.

I'm using spring mvc so the form uses a backing object which needs to be filled with data from the form. The products that I want to add need to come in a list of the backing object.

In the form I also want to calculate the total price. So I need more info than I got in the product list.

I rather not post it to the backend as json but just use @ModelAttribute.

Could it be possible to somehow give the complete object (product) to the form when clicking it in the list?

Hopefully I've explained myself well enough else just ask.

Here are the source codes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('/oms/ajax/products', function(data) {  
        $.each(data, function(key, obj) {
            $('#productList').append('<li onclick=\"addProduct(' + obj.productName + ')\">' + obj.productName + '</li>');
        });
    });
});

function addProduct(name) {
    $('#orderItems').append('<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"order.lineItems[i]\" value=\"' + name + '\" /></li>');
}

public class OrderDTO {
    private List<OrderItemDTO> lineItems;
    /** getters and setters **/
}

public class OrderItemDTO {

    private String productCode;
    private String productName;
    private String description;
    private Float price;
    private Integer quantity;
    /** getters and setters **/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will need to do is fiddle with the Form's DOM, adding and removing the items as hidden input fields.

Spring MVC handles Collections of items by sub-script.  This works for both List and Maps the same way.  For a list:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="myModel">
   <form:hidden path="myListItems[0].name" />
   <form:hidden path="myListItems[1].name" />

   <form:hidden path="myMapItems['key1'].name" />
   <form:hidden path="myMapItems['someOtherKey'].name" />
</form:form>
```

This shows the normal way to add two items to a list or two items to a map.  This uses the Spring JSTL tags to build the form.  However, you will need to do this dynamically, so instead you will be adding something like the following:

This is how Spring will generate the second list item above.  The key to making it work is getting the name attribute right.  Basically, all the Spring JSTL tags will generate some sort of form input.  The best way to get things to work is to see how it does it using the JSTL tags, then simply duplicate the resulting HTML tags.

Once you get a handle on how to get the inputs right, now its a simple matter of writting some JavaScript to dynamically add the right inputs to the form.  It looks like you are using jQuery, so you can do something like:

```
var myModel= $('#myModel);
$("<input />",{
  type: 'hidden',
  id: 'myListItems1.name',
  name: 'myListItems[1].name',
  value: 'someValue'
}).appendTo(myModel);
```

Here, #myModel is the generated ID for the form.  We are simply creating an input element, and appending it to the form.  Simple enough.

Here is where you get into issues, however.  Spring MVC uses simple setters to get/set values in your Model Attribute.  This means you can easily get and set a value in your List/Map, but it also means that Spring MVC doesn't remove items already there if the Model Attribute is in Session.  What I mean by this can be explained in the following example.

Say your user adds 3 items to their order and previews it.  Once it makes the round-trip to your controller you now have 3 items in your Model Atttribute's collection (elements at index 0, 1, and 2 if its a list and your numbers are sequential). Now lets say the user decides he doesn't want item 2 (index 1), and removes it.  So, naturally your JavaScript will remove that item from the Form.  However, when the user submits, even though the form doesn't contain the item at index 1 any longer, its still in the Model Attribute's collection.  This is because Spring MVC will only set things that are passed in from the Form submission.  It doesn't keep track of things that were not set.

So, what you have to do for removes is somehow keep track of them.  There are two ways I have accomplished this.  The first is to add a removal flag to the Objects in my collection.  The flag is a simple boolean that, when true, the Controller/Service layer knows that this item was removed and to ignore it.  The way this is implemented in the JavaScript is that, upon removing an item, you simply replace/add another hidden input for the removal flag and set that to "true".

The second option is to shift all your items up on removal, such that all legitamate items are 1-N.  Upon submission of the form, you would send the "valid" count along with the Model Attribute (as a separate RequestParam or a value in the Model Attribute directly).  The Controller/Service layer then knows how many should be in the list, and can trim off the ones that don't belong.

I can tell you, getting all of this to work well is a challenge no matter which way you go, and you will need a firm understanding of how Spring works.  I would highly suggest writting some simple test apps, see what Spring generates (especially in the View), and try to get your head around it.

As for how you implement all of this, it's totally up to how you want to code things.  I tend to try and limit the amount of data I keep in the View, so my approach might be to only send a list of item numbers and quantities in the order.  I think this is especially important for a ordering system because people can manipulate your JavaScript, and some nefarious person will end up changing the price of an item in their shopping cart and end up ripping you off.  Never trust what the Browser sends.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew half but this post made me see the complete picture. I used jquery to add products to the order form and only send the product id's and quantity to the controller.